# Package textpos disagreeing with figure caption font and format

Tags: floats, captions, textpos

I'm trying to place a number of images at specific places in a book (in fact, most of the pages will consist only of images and the respective captions), for which I'm using the textpos-package. At the same time, I'm trying to modifiy the format of my figures, for which I'm using the caption-package.

However, using textpos to place the image, does away with my caption formatting. Any hints welcome.

Here's a mwe:

```
\documentclass[12pt,german,twoside,openany]{book} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding (not needed with XeLaTeX)
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} % support the \includegraphics command and options
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pagecolor=none]{pagecolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[absolute,showboxes]{textpos}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[papersize={30cm,30cm},total={25cm,25cm},top=2cm,inner=3cm,footskip=2cm]{geometry} % to change the page dimensions
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{10mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{10mm}{10mm} % start everything near the top-left corner
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf,small},labelformat={default},textfont={it,small},format={hang},name={Abb.},justification=centerlast}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{-5pt}
\title{Titel}
\author{Stephan Natschläger}
\date{} % Activate to display a given date or no date (if empty),
         % otherwise the current date is printed 
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagestyle{plain}
\chapter{kapitel 1} \label{chap_1}
\begin{textblock}{12}(8,13)
 \begin{figure}[H]
  \includegraphics[width=120mm]{20200705_JKU_IR_700_0011}
  \label{fig:20200705_JKU_IR_700_0011}
  \caption{JKU, some description}
\end{figure}
\end{textblock}
\newpage
 \begin{figure}[H]
  \includegraphics[width=250mm]{20200705_JKU_IR_700_0011}
  \label{fig:20200705_JKU_IR_700_0011}
  \caption{JKU, some description}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and here are the two resulting images
[image: This is not what I want]

[image: This is what I want]

Comment: remove the figure environment and use `\captionof{figure}{JKU, some description}` for the caption.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick 